# How do Shaper and Coordinator work in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, architecture

Hellow Community!

Can you please explain how do [Coordinator](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Entity/System/Data/Common/Internal/Materialization/Coordinator.cs) and [Shaper](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Entity/System/Data/Common/Internal/Materialization/Shaper.cs) work for materialization?

Particularly interested in the hierarchical read of nested collections.

In more details, i need to have a simplified implementation of Shaper+Coordinator to convert source:

```
var source = new[]
        {
            new Record { Id = 1, Subject = "How to", PartyId = 81, FirstName = "Dart Vaider", LabelId = 51, Tag = "Important" },
            new Record { Id = 1, Subject = "How to", PartyId = 81, FirstName = "Dart Vaider", LabelId = 52, Tag = "Urgent" },
            new Record { Id = 1, Subject = "How to", PartyId = 82, FirstName = "Lea Organo", LabelId = 51, Tag = "Important" },
            new Record { Id = 1, Subject = "How to", PartyId = 82, FirstName = "Lea Organo", LabelId = 52, Tag = "Urgent" },

            new Record { Id = 2, Subject = "Just do it", PartyId = 83, FirstName = "Luk Skywalker", LabelId = 51, Tag = "Important" },
            new Record { Id = 2, Subject = "Just do it", PartyId = 83, FirstName = "Luk Skywalker", LabelId = 52, Tag = "Urgent" },
            new Record { Id = 2, Subject = "Just do it", PartyId = 83, FirstName = "Luk Skywalker", LabelId = 55, Tag = "Interesting" },
            new Record { Id = 2, Subject = "Just do it", PartyId = 84, FirstName = "Han Solo", LabelId = 51, Tag = "Important" },
            new Record { Id = 2, Subject = "Just do it", PartyId = 84, FirstName = "Han Solo", LabelId = 52, Tag = "Urgent" },
            new Record { Id = 2, Subject = "Just do it", PartyId = 84, FirstName = "Han Solo", LabelId = 55, Tag = "Interesting" },
        };
```

to the list of `Email`s considering the following structure

```
public class Email
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Asuming, that actual materialization of Record -> Email, Record -> Contact, Record -> Tag are primitive, no need to concentrate on this.

Thank you very much for help

Comment: Well, if you first explain what you *don't* understand... No, this question is too broad for Stack Overflow. Also, you're asking the wrong audience, ask the ones who made the code.

Comment: And, by the way, I'm not even sure if later EF versions still use these .Net classes, I don't think so. If you like you could check EF's source code.

Comment: thank you for your answer. agree, this is a too broad question, but please see my comment below the answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I am presuming the example is a simplified version of your actual data, but it seems unclear what you are trying to do in regards to `Shaper` and `Coordinator`.

The example of converting our `source` collection in to a collection `Email` objects can be done with linq.

```
var emails = source.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(x => new Email()
        {
            Id = x.Key,
            Subject = x.Select(z => z.Subject).First(),
            Contacts = x.GroupBy(g => g.PartyId)
                .Select(s => new Contact() {Id = s.Key, FirstName = s.Select(z => z.FirstName).First()}).ToList(),
            Tags = x.GroupBy(g => g.LabelId)
                .Select(s => new Tag() {Id = s.Key, Text = s.Select(z => z.Tag).First()}).ToList()
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. This is exactly what i'm trying to do.
However, how can do it in a more generalized way? When the hierarchy of objects is defined in runtime? 

Now we have a tree: 
Email - root
Tag and Contact - sibling leaves.

But entity framework when reading the data from IDataReader uses Shaper and Coordinator to convert the plain list of joined records into an object hierarchy. No linq, just some kind of magic there. And i'm struggling understanding how it works.

Please let me know if i'm not clear enough

Comment: you're absolutely right, this example is simplified.
actual source data is `IDataReader` 
+ some kind of set of compiled expressions: `Func<IDataRecord, Email>`, `Func<IDataRecord, Contact>`, `Func<IDataRecord, Tag>`
+ some kind of hierarchy, that defines the order and structure of reads